# massive iteration

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a suggestion for the best way to achieve a solution to this problem.  I have a table with 135 unique outcomes (prices), each price will effect the outcome of three seperate derivatives, as the price changes, so does the value of each of the three derivatives.  Each derivative can have any 1 of up to 21 different quanities attached to it, of which the quanity of the derivative is multipied by the price outcome to get a result for a specific derivative quanity and price.

I have crossjoined the derivative to get all of the unique combonations (90,000+), but when I try to cross join the possible combonations with the prices, the system is too slow and often stops responding.  I have also tried to insert each possible combonation using a while loop, extract the statistics needed and then run the next senerio, but to no avail.

In short, what is the best way to form a realitively massive crossjoin or iteration.

Matt

Comment: What will you do with the result? What is this for?

Comment: maximum `135*3*21` records - I think that you can run the calculations in a code, no need to run it in the DB.